# How can I set the width of a second level Mmenu menu?

Tags: mmenu

I have successfully setup Mmenu on a WordPress theme - loving Mmenu so far. But I need to change the width of the second level menu to make it a little wider than the top level menu.

I can change the width of the parent container, however this affects the top level menu too.

```
.mm-menu {
    width:320px !important;
}
```

I am open to CSS or Javascript solutions. Although I don't think a CSS solution is possible.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the width by changing the values on the media query "@media all and (min-width: 440px;){html.mm-opening .mm-slideout {}}".